# How to exclude getter/setter methods from test coverage in sonar clover plugin?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, clover

We use Jenkins CI with Sonar for test coverage. 
We use Atlassian Clover as coverage tool. 
So the question: how to exclude getter/setter methods from test coverage in order to increase test coverage percent without writing useless test cases?
I have tried to make some changes in Settings->General Settings->Clover and Settings->General Settings->Java sections but without any success.
As I understand I need to apply something like (.* )?public .*(get|set|is)[A-Z0-9].* but I don't know where should I put this expression.

Comment: Not to be contrary, but why wouldn't you test getters and setters?   There's a classic location for copy/paste errors.  (Unless you're using Groovy or something that's creating those for you).

Answer (score 2):

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-766 is currently planned for version 4.1. Feel free to watch it.